# Strange program behaviour

Tags: java, exception

This elementary program is driving me up the wall.
There must be something very simple I don't see here.
WHY is the exception triggered?

There are 2 classes:
1)

```
public class Person
{
private String name;
private int age;
private static int numberOfPeople = 0;

public Person()
{
    this("John Doe", 0);
    numberOfPeople++;
}
public Person(String name, int age)
{
    this.setAge(age);
    this.setName(name);
    numberOfPeople++;
}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public int getAge() {
    return age;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public void setAge(int age) {
    this.age = age;
}
public int getNumberOfPersons()
{
    return numberOfPeople;
}
public String toString()
{
    return this.name + " " + this.age;
}

}
```

2)

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Adult extends Person
{
private String number;
public static final int MIN_AGE = 18;

public Adult(String name, int age, String number)
{
    super(name, 0);
    this.setAge(age);
    this.number = number;
}
public Adult(Adult adult)
{
    this(adult.getName(), adult.getAge(), adult.getNumber());
}
public Adult()
{
    this.number = "";
    this.setAge(MIN_AGE);
    Random rand = new Random();
    int result = rand.nextInt(2);
    if (result == 0)
    {
        this.setName("John Doe");
    }
    else
    {
        this.setName("Jane Doe");
    }
}
public void setAge(int age)
{
    if (age < MIN_AGE)
    {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("The person must be 18 or older!");
    }
    else
    {
        super.setAge(MIN_AGE);
    }
}
public String getNumber()
{
    return this.number;
}
private void setNumber(String number)
{
    this.number = number;
}
public String toString()
{
    return this.getName() + " " + this.getNumber() + " " + this.getAge();
}
public boolean equals(Object obj)
{
    boolean result = false;
    if (obj != null && this.getClass() == obj.getClass())
    {
        Adult other = (Adult) obj;
        if (this.getName().equals(other.getName()) &&
                this.getNumber().equals(other.getNumber()) &&
                this.getAge() == other.getAge())
        {
            result = true;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Adult ad = new Adult();
    System.out.println(ad);
}
}
```

This gives my the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The person must be 18 or older!
at people.Adult.setAge(Adult.java:39)
at people.Person.<init>(Person.java:16)
at people.Adult.<init>(Adult.java:12)
at people.Adult.main(Adult.java:75)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `Person()` constructor creates another person. Since Adult extends Person, there is an implicit `super()` call which is likely the cause of your error.

Comment: It is indeed the cause of the error. The stack trace makes this very easy.

Comment: Okay, so Adult() makes a call to Person(), and that attempts to create a Person object. But why does the exception occur? Is the overriden method setAge() used for Person??

Comment: Line 16 of Person is inside the `Person(name, age)` constructor. Line 75 of Adult is a bracket. While I was reasonably certain that this was the case & the difference was just due to missing lines, I still like caveats. As you (I think it was you @Paul Draper) pointed out, there are other cases which could cause the error if a different version were being executed. OP: If `Person()` called `Person(name, age)` then you'd be instantiating a new person. `this` inherits Adulthood from the `Adult()` constructor.

Comment: Did not quite understand the last sentence. "there is an implicit super() call which is likely the cause of your error." Could you elaborate? Why does the error occur there?

Comment: `Person()` calls `this("John Doe", 0)`. If it called `Person("John Doe", 0)` it would always create another Person. When you call `Adult()`, java implicitly calls `super()` because you didn't call `super` with a different method signature. `Adult extends Person`, so `super()` is your `Person()` constructor. At that point `this` refers to an Adult, so a `(String, int)` constructor for Adult is found in Person, creating an Adult who violates the age requirement.

Comment: @cjc343's explanation is correct. When an object is created the parent constructors are run in order, starting with `Object` and ending with the class itself. `super` allows you to choose the parent constructor, but if none is specified, the default (no arguments) constructor is used. If it were not so, you could wind up with an `Adult` whose `Person`hood has not been properly created.